# how to get exit status from the command before the last

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, solaris, command

I have solaris machine ( solaris 10 )

please Look on the following simple commands (haconf -makerw | grep -iq "Cluster already writable")

```
    # haconf -makerw 
      VCS WARNING V-16-1-10364 Cluster already writable.


    haconf -makerw | grep -iq "Cluster already writable"
    # echo $?
    0
```

I get exit status 0 from grep ,

and this is right ( because we get the exe status always the last command )

but

my question is:

how to get the exit status ( $? ) from the command **haconf -makerw**  in place of grep?

or what need to add in to my syntax in order to understand if haconf -makerw succeeded ?

```
    haconf -makerw | grep -iq "Cluster already writable"
    # echo $? ( will print the exe status from haconf -makerw  )
```