# How do I capture the return status and use tee at the same time in korn shell?

Tags: shell-script, ksh

Consider Source code:

**1. Parent.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
# No tee
ksh Child.sh;
exit_status=$?;
echo "Exit status: ${exit_status}"
# Using tee
ksh Child.sh | tee -a log.txt;
exit_status=$?;
echo "Exit status: ${exit_status}"
```

**2. Child.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
...
exit 1;
```

**Output:**

```
Exit status: 1
Exit status: 0
```

---

- Variable `$exit_status` is capturing the exit status of Child.sh and so is `1`.
- In the 2nd case, `$exit_status` is capturing the exit status of tee, which is `0`.

So how do I capture the exit status and also use tee?

Comment: Hi @lesmana - Note that this question is asking for a `ksh` solution. Using `$PIPESTATUS` only works in bash - all solution I can find on unix.stackexchange.com are for bash.

Comment: Seems the solution (workaround) for ksh is to use Pipefail.. I will test and confirm the same assuming this question is not incorrectly closed by then..

Comment: I am aware that this question is marked ksh. I suggested the duplicate because the other question is not marked as bash specific and not all answers are bash specific.

Comment: In answers to that other question, you'll find POSIX answers. See also the [comp.unix.shell FAQ](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html‎)

Comment: Gotcha @lesmana.  Well this [solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73170/how-to-get-exit-status-from-the-command-before-the-last/73180#73180) explains pipefail well, which can be used for korn. [Reference](http://cybergav.in/2009/11/15/how-to-check-the-exit-status-of-a-pipeline-in-unix-kshbash/)

Comment: Hi @StephaneChazelas - I checked that, seems like the site has been suspended.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reproduced (and improved) from the [comp.unix.shell FAQ](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=comp.unix.shell/UHX-bBndq7k/KWoxBv7fCHoJ) (since I happen to have written that section of the FAQ):

### How do I get the exit code of cmd1 in cmd1|cmd2

First, note that cmd1 exit code could be non-zero and still don't
mean an error. This happens for instance in

```
cmd | head -n 1
```

you might observe a 141 (or 269 with ksh93, or 397 with yash) exit status of `cmd`,
but it's because `cmd` was interrupted by a SIGPIPE signal when
`head -n 1` terminated after having read one line.

To know the exit status of the elements of a pipeline

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3
```

#### with zsh (and fish 3.1+):

The exit codes are provided in the `pipestatus` special array.
`cmd1` exit code is in `$pipestatus[1]`, `cmd3` exit code in
`$pipestatus[3]`, so that `$status`/`$?` is always the same as
`$pipestatus[-1]`.

#### with bash:

The exit codes are provided in the `PIPESTATUS` special array.
`cmd1` exit code is in `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`, `cmd3` exit code in
`${PIPESTATUS[2]}`, so that `$?` is always the same as
`${PIPESTATUS[-1]}` (or `${PIPESTATUS[@]: -1}` for versions older than 4.2).

#### with any other Bourne like shells

You need to use a trick to pass the exit codes to the main shell.  You can do
it using a pipe(2). Instead of running `cmd1`, you run `cmd1; echo "$?"` and make
sure $? makes its way to the shell.

```
exec 3>&1
code=`
  # now, inside the backticks, fd4 goes to the pipe
  # whose other end is read and stored in $code  for
  # later evaluation; fd1 is the normal standard output
  # preserved the line before with exec 3>&1

  exec 4>&1 >&3 3>&- 
  {
    cmd1 4>&-; echo "ec1=$?;" >&4
  } | {
    cmd2 4>&-; echo "ec2=$?;" >&4
  } | cmd3 4>&-
  echo "ec3=$?;" >&4
`
exec 3>&-
eval "$code"
```

Exit codes in `$ec1`, `$ec2`, `$ec3`.

#### with a POSIX shell

You can use this function to make it easier:

```
run() {
  j=1
  while eval "\${pipestatus_$j+:} false"; do
    unset "pipestatus_$j"
    j=$(($j+1))
  done
  j=1 com= k=1 l=
  for arg do
    case $arg in
      ('|')
        com="$com {
               $l "'3>&-
               echo "pipestatus_'$j'=$?" >&3
             } 4>&- |'
        j=$(($j+1)) l=;;
      (*)
        l="$l \"\${$k}\""
    esac
    k=$(($k+1))
  done
  com="$com $l"' 3>&- >&4 4>&-
       echo "pipestatus_'$j'=$?"'

  { eval "$(exec 3>&1; eval "$com")"; } 4>&1
  j=1
  ret=0
  while eval "\${pipestatus_$j+:} false"; do
    eval '[ "$pipestatus_'"$j"'" -eq 0 ] || ret=$pipestatus_'"$j"
    j=$(($j+1))
  done
  return "$ret"
}
```

Use it as:

```
run cmd1 \| cmd2 \| cmd3
```

exit codes are in `$pipestatus_1`, `$pipestatus_2`, `$pipestatus_3` and `$?` is the right-most non-zero exit status (like with the `pipefail` option of some shells).

Comment: Should `cmd3` be `cmd3 4>&-`, like `cmd1` and `cmd2`?

Comment: @hvd, you're right `cmd3` doesn't need that fd 4 either, so we might as well close it. See edit with a few other improvements.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You can use && and || to do it in bash - I assume something similar will work in ksh.</strike>

```
ksh Child.sh && exit_status="$?" || exit_status="$?" | tee -a log.txt;
```

**EDIT:**

As @Stephane points out, `A && B | C` will output A to stdout, and only pipe B to C. It needs to group the outputs, to pipe them together. You can't pass a variable from a subshell into the caller, but, you can do this:

```
x=$(tempfile) && exit_status=$(ksh Child.sh > $x; echo $?) && (cat $x; rm $x) | tee -a log.txt
```

Comment: That pipes the (non-)output of `exit_status="$?"` to `tee`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Yes, but it also pipes the output of child.sh to tee. Try it yourself: `echo a && exit_status="$?" | cat -`. You'll see it still echoes "a"

Comment: You'll see "a" as well with `echo a && whatever | tr a b`, since that's running `echo a` and then run `whatever | tr a b` if `echo a` was successful.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Yes, it seems you're right. My mistake - I'll update the answer now.