# returncode of command in a pipline

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, solaris, ksh

The following script runs on Solaris using */bin/ksh* and on Linux using */bin/sh*

```
cmd | tee -a  cmd.log | tail
exit $?
```

The output of *cmd* is saved in a file *cmd.log* and the last lines are  displayed on  `stdout`.

The purpose of `exit $?` was to exit the script  with the return code of *cmd*. Of course this

does not work because `$?` holds the return code of the last command in the pipeline which is

`tail`.

Workaround (I will omit all cleanup activities) :

```
{ cmd;  echo $? >  error.file; } | tee -a  cmd.log | tail
exit `cat error.file`
```

But is there another way to get the returncode of *cmd* and  to avoid the creation of a file like *error.file*?

Comment: Have you seen [this Q & A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76162/how-do-i-capture-the-return-status-and-use-tee-at-the-same-time-in-korn-shell)?

Comment: Looks like `set -o pipefail` works in bash and ksh.

Comment: @Kevin: set -o pipefail did not work on Solaris 10, "bad option"

Comment: @Kevin: I see it is a duplicate now and your link contains the answers

Comment: @Joseph R. : I see it is a duplicate now and your link contains the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(cmd; echo $? 1>&2) | tee -a  cmd.log | tail
```

Or, if you want to redirect STDERR to tee:

```
exec 3>&1; (cmd 2>&1; echo $? >&3 3>&-)| tee -a  cmd.log; exec 3>&-
```

Comment: How should this work? That writes to the logfile and  the output.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can write echo output to stderr.