# Chaining pipe | with &&

Tags: shell, pipe, exit-status

I have this command where I want to filter `make` output:

```
cd /app && make && sudo nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

What is the correct way to insert `make | pv -q -L 100` here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get exit status of process that's piped to another](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, the linked question doesn't answer how to chain pipes and && correctly.

Comment: See also [How do I get the exit code of cmd1 in cmd1|cmd2](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76171)

Comment: Yes, you're right, the problematic and solutions will be the same, but it's a slightly different question. I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you'll be checking the exit status of `pv`. With POSIX `sh` syntax, you could do:

```
cd /app && ((make 3>&- && exec sudo nginx -g 'daemon off;' >&3 3>&-) | pv -qL 100) 3>&1
```

Or with `ksh`/`bash`/`zsh`:

```
(set -o pipefail
cd /app && make | pv -qL 100 && sudo nginx -g 'daemon off;')
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
cd /app && make | pv -qL 100 && ((!pipestatus[1])) && sudo nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Or with `bash`:

```
cd /app && make | pv -qL 100 && ((!PIPESTATUS[0])) && sudo nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Comment: OMG. I knew the answer won't be easy. =)

Comment: Gives me `[STDERR] /bin/sh: 1: !PIPESTATUS[0]: not found`. I run this command with CMD from Dockerfile.

Comment: @techtonik, as I said, `PIPESTATUS` is for `bash`. For `sh`, use the first one.

Comment: Ended up with `CMD bash -c "(set -o pipefail; cd /app && make | pv -q -L 150 && sudo nginx -g 'daemon off;')"`