# adapt 'exec &> >(tee -a "$LOG_FILE")' to sh

Tags: shell, posix

In `bash`, this:

```
exec &> >(tee -a "$LOG_FILE")
```

Will redirect `stderr` & `stdout` to `tee` that allows the output to be displayed on the terminal while also logged (written to `$LOG_FILE`), but it uses process substitution, a feature not available in `sh`

If I run the script with sh:

```
sh script
```

I get:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

In my attempt to have the same result in `sh`, I tried:

```
exec 2>&1 | tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
```

But I notice that nothing gets written to `$LOG_FILE`, instead I had to use:

```
exec > "$LOG_FILE" 2>&1
```

That writes the log to the file, but I don't see any output when running the script.

Any ideas?

From the accepted answer, the usage of:

```
mkfifo "$HOME/.pipe.$$"
```

helps/complements the suggested answer, since allows to have the code  inline and not within a block

Comment: what is `sh` though? in my system it's a symlink to `dash`, what is it in yours?

Comment: is `/usr/bin/sh`

Comment: @nbari, Jaromanda is asking about the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/sh`.  For me it is: `/usr/bin/sh -> dash`.

Comment: that error message (with the backtick as the opening quote) looks like one from an old version of Bash, one that doesn't support process substitution. You should probably [edit] to mention your system. Also, the Bourne shell is a historical ancestor of the current (POSIX) sh, you probably don't have that. (Unless you're running something like Solaris that might be stuck in the past a bit.)

Comment: `/usr/bin/sh` is usually a symlink, what is it linked to

Comment: Interesting that I see that sh is linked to bash: `/usr/bin/sh -> bash` (testing on a red-hat 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
#!/bin/sh
#
LOG_FILE=/tmp/log_file    # Demonstration target

# Set up the redirection to `tee`
mkfifo "$HOME/.pipe.$$"
tee -a "$LOG_FILE" <"$HOME/.pipe.$$" &
exec 1>"$HOME/.pipe.$$" 2>&1
rm -f "$HOME/.pipe.$$"

# Using the redirection
echo hello
date
echo STDERR >&2

exit 0
```

The guts of the conversion revolves around creating the pipe, redirecting *stdin* for the `tee`, and redirecting *stdout* and *stderr* for the remainder of the process. In the middle of that is the invocation of `tee` itself:

```
tee -a "$LOG_FILE" <"$HOME/.pipe.$$" &
```

Here we're writing (appending) to `"$LOG_FILE"` by reading from the pipe we created just a moment earlier, and the trailing `&` runs the command in the background - as usual. Once the pipe has been opened on both sides (writer and reader) it can be deleted from the filesystem: it still exists and can be used until both sides are finished with it, but it is no longer accessible by name.

In an [earlier edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/745366/2) of this script I captured the PID of the `tee` command into the variable `$tpid`, ready for killing it at the end of the script. However, it was correctly pointed out to me that I don't have to kill the `tee` process at the end of the script because it'll get a fatal `SIGPIPE` anyway once the writer finally closes the pipe.

In production code I assume you'll have `$LOG_FILE` writing somewhere safe. I've dropped it into `/tmp` simply as a placeholder for the remainder of the code to function.

Comment: Creating (or writing to) files with fixed names in world-writable areas such as `/tmp` is bad practice from a security standpoint, I would not advertise such practice.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the guts of the code doesn't write to `/tmp` for exactly the same reasons as you're highlighting. I don't care about `$LOG_FILE` but it was a given in the question so I left it as capitals and simply pinned it somewhere

Comment: `tee -a "$LOG_FILE"` writes to that file. If someone has made a `ln -s /bin/sh /tmp/log_file` and you're running this as root for instance, that will wreak havoc.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas LOG_FILE isn't my problem and not relevant to the code being demonstrated

Comment: The problem is with *your* `LOG_FILE=/tmp/log_file` line which should be `LOG_FILE=/var/log/file.log` or `LOG_FILE=~/.local/file.log`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
LOG_FILE=/var/log/myscript.log
{
  the whole script here:
  ...
} 2>&1 | tee -a -- "$LOGFILE"
```

Or:

```
#! /bin/sh -
LOG_FILE=/var/log/myscript.log
main() {
  the whole script here:
  ...
}
main "$@" 2>&1 | tee -a -- "$LOGFILE"
```

Beware the script exit status will be `tee`'s though. That can be worked around with the `pipefail` option, but though that option will be standard in `sh` in the next version of the standard, there are still some `sh` implementations that don't support it (most notably `dash`). See [How do I capture the return status and use tee at the same time in korn shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76162) for other approaches.

Note that while `sh` was generally the Bourne shell in the 80s (succeeding to the Thompson shell), nowadays, `sh` is one or the other implementation of an interpreter for the standard POSIX `sh` language which is based on a subset of that of ksh88 (a Bourne shell derivative),  not the Bourne shell.  Process substitution is from ksh (ksh86 initially), but has not been specified for `sh` by POSIX and is not available in shells derived from the Almquist shell (initially a clone of the Bourne shell) or the Forsyth shell (including pdksh/mksh even though they were initially meant to be clones of the Korn shell). It's also not available in ksh88 on systems that don't support `/dev/fd/n`.